# how to? bootstrap - 2 Columns with 3 rows with equal height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 columns with 3 "rows" (or three Items). I want to have row 1 in both columns with same height, in row 2 and row 3 the same.

I know how to do this with 3 rows having 2 columns. But using 3 rows with two columns will not work on small device, because the left columns should be first and right column at the end.

I want on Desktop something like:

```
A1|B1 
A1|right row is same height, but less content than A1

A2|B2
no content|B2
no content|B2

A3|B3
```

On mobile it should be:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

If i use 3 rows with two columns I get it work with equal height for each row on desktop, but on mobile i have:

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specific required cannot be solved by constructing 3 row 2 column.

You should try to wrap all the leftone(s) into a single div and all the rightone(s) into a single div. Something like this

```
<div id="left" class="col-md-8">
  A1<br></br>
  A2<br></br>
  A3<br></br>
</div>
<div id="right" class="col-md-8">
  B1<br></br>
  B2<br></br>
  B3<br></br>
</div>
```

This way in normal desktop version it would look like

```
A1    B1
A2    B2
A3    B3
```

In Mobile version it should look like what you wanted

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

**(Note: You need to manage the height of each element like A1, B1, A2, B2 to make it look like they are 3x2 table but actually it is 1X2.)**

Comment: col-span-5? Never came across such a class.

Comment: but how should i manage it? Every element has a Picture and Text. picture are all same height and with and using img-responsive class its fine. But there is short and long text.